# tcl regex with variables

Tags: regex, tcl, cisco

I need to verify what ip address is announce the default route:

```
set command [ exec "show ip route" ]
```

the ouput:

```
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is 10.17.1.252 to network 0.0.0.0

B*    0.0.0.0/0 [200/0] via 10.17.1.252, 01:16:22
      10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        10.17.1.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet1/0
L        10.17.1.253/32 is directly connected, FastEthernet1/0
      172.22.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C        172.22.12.250 is directly connected, Loopback1
      172.26.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 2 masks
B        172.26.69.64/30 [200/0] via 10.17.1.252, 01:16:33
C        172.26.70.64/30 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
L        172.26.70.66/32 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
```

I need to find this: "0.0.0.0/0 [200/0] via 10.17.1.252", but this address: 10.17.1.252 can change, how I can put a variable in a regex ?

```
set routes [ regexp {(0.0.0.0\/0 \[200\/0\] via $bgp_neighbor)} $command match default_route ]
```

Comment: So, `$bgp_neighbor` contains the IP address you need to use as part of the regex, right? And what value do you expect for `default_route`?

Comment: yes, $bgp_neighbor contain the IP address. actually I need verify only if is true, if the default route with that ip exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression isn't the best choice for this.

```
string first [format {0.0.0.0/0 [200/0] via %s} $bgp_neighbor] $command
```

When searching for a zero variance pattern, `string first` is the closest match. Building the pattern with `format` minimizes the amount of escaping you need to do.

In this case, there isn't much escaping needed anyway:

```
string first "0.0.0.0/0 \[200/0] via $bgp_neighbor" $command
```

Note that `string first` returns the position of the string if found, or -1 if not found.

Documentation:
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: your solution of yours is also interesting and managed to incorporate in the remaining code I have, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a dynamic regex keeping in mind that unescaped `.` match any char in regex, and that is why you need to [*escape* the dynamic part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042826/escape-string-for-putting-it-into-regex-in-tcl) before adding it to the regex.

Here is a way to solve the issue (`$a` is the variable holding the text):

```
proc reEscape {str} {
    regsub -all {\W} $str {\\&}
}
set bgp_neighbor {10.17.1.252}
set bgp_neighbor_escaped [reEscape $bgp_neighbor]
set reg {\y0\.0\.0\.0/0 \[200/0] via }
append reg $bgp_neighbor_escaped
append reg {\y}

if {[regexp $reg $a]} {
  puts yes
} else {
  puts no
}
```

See the [Tcl demo](https://ideone.com/QjgS5t)

Here, `$bgp_neighbor` holds the IP address. The `$bgp_neighbor_escaped` is the same string with all non-word chars escaped (you will actually have `.` replaced with `\.`). The `\y` are word boundaries, in order to avoid matching `152.1.0.23` in `2222152.1.0.234444`.

Note you may replace all literal spaces with `\s+` to match any 1+ whitespace chars.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, just perfect!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: R1(tcl)#proc reEscape {str} {
+>    regsub -all {\W} $str {\\&}
+>}
R1(tcl)#set bgp_neighbor {172.26.69.65}
172.26.69.65
R1(tcl)#set bgp_neighbor_escaped [reEscape $bgp_neighbor]
wrong # args: should be "regsub ?switches? exp string subSpec varName"
R1(tcl)#set reg {\y0\.0\.0\.0/0 \[20/0] via }
\y0\.0\.0\.0/0 \[20/0] via 
R1(tcl)#append reg $bgp_neighbor_escaped
can't read "bgp_neighbor_escaped": no such variable
R1(tcl)#append reg {\y}
\y0\.0\.0\.0/0 \[20/0] via \y
R1(tcl)#
is not working in different version of IOS or if i put inside of proc

Comment: @CFRR Have a look at Peter's solution, it might be what you need for the current scenario.